# Switch emacs frames by their position on x-display

Tags: emacs, frames

Is there a way to switch emacs frames by keyboard in order they located on the X-display (left->right, top->bottom, ...)?

For example if I see 4 emacs frames on my screen:
[image]

then want to switch between them by keys in correspondent visual order (no matter when they created).

After if I for example swap two top frames, the switching to the "next" frame should change correspondingly as they are located on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think the package `framemove.el` does what you described: see [the source](https://github.com/emacsmirror/framemove/blob/master/framemove.el) or the author's [blog post](http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2010/02/emacs-tip-35-framemove.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).